# xslt and xml - not rendering ( Once i am able to render this ill render the rest)

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I am trying to give a stylesheet to the below xml: However I just dont know whats wrong with my xpath. I have tried referring to every website however It just doesnt render.

```
<careTeames> 
   <careteame> 
      <PCP>JONES,MARY</PCP> 
       <type>Ped - Under 5</type> 
       <caregivers/> 
       <providers> 
         <provider>Henderson,Wilson</provider>
         <providertype>Cardilogist</providertype>
         <provider>H,WILLIAM</provider> 
         <providertype>OPTHOMOLGY</providertype> 
       </providers>
   </careteame>
   <careteame> 
      <PCP>JONES,MARY2</PCP> 
       <type>Ped - Under 5</type> 
       <caregivers/> 
       <providers> 
         <provider>Henderson,Wilson2</provider>
         <providertype>Cardilogist2</providertype>
         <provider>H,WILLIAM2</provider> 
         <providertype>OPTHOMOLGY2</providertype> 
       </providers>
    </careteame>
</careTeames>
```

I just want a simple output to be :

```
PCP       JONES, MARY 
PROVIDERS Henderson, Wilson
          H, William
```

My xsl is able to produce the first line of PCP however the other for-each fails :(

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Data</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="return/careTeames/careteame">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="PCP" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="type" /></td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="return/careTeames/careteame/caremanagers">
                        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="caremanagertype"/></td><td>( <xsl:value-of select="caremanagertype"/> )</td></tr>
      </xsl:for-each>   
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="return/careTeames/careteame">
```

Then within the **xsl:for-each** loop your current context will be the **careteame**. This means the nested **xsl:for-each** will be relative to this. That is to say it will be looking for the path `return/careTeames/careteame/caremanagers` as a descendant of the current node.

So, instead of doing this

```
<xsl:for-each select="return/careTeames/careteame/caremanagers">
```

All you really need to do at this point is this

```
<xsl:for-each select="caremanagers">
```

Or rather, you need to do this, as there is no **caremanagers** in your XML sample (nor is there any **return** element).

```
<xsl:for-each select="providers/provider">
```

Actually, it is often better to use template matching, rather than **xsl:for-each**. Try this XSLT, which matches your current XML sample

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>Data</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th>col1</th>
                  <th>col2</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="return/careTeames/careteame"/>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="careteame">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="PCP"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="providers/provider"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="provider">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works . I am just editing the path in the apply templates tag. It should be return/careTeames/careteame.